# Terminal multiplexer for vim based IDE on Ubuntu?

Tags: terminal-emulator, vim, terminal-multiplexer

Which terminal multiplexer should I use for my vim based IDE? Right now I am using tmux. In overall it's quite good.

However its somehow painful to get mouse based copy & paste between panes/splits and other destinations/sources (e.g. text from browser) configured the right way. Another not so nice thing about tmux is that the screen hangs and needs to be resotred from freeze via F5 quite frequently.

Requirements:

- OS: Ubuntu
- installable via deb package
- Features:

  - tmux like sessions
  - windows/tabs
  - panes/splits
- smooth integration with vim

Possible choices:

- Byobu
- neercs
- screen
- terminator
- (tmux)
- twin

Comment: YMMV, but I've had better luck using vim inside GNU screen than inside tmux.  Getting mouse integration working properly is still a pain, but I've never had issues with screen freezing on me.

Comment: new vim also has a :terminal command